# {} in .cabal for Haddock-documentation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, cabal, haddock

If I got the line

```
> { -# OPTIONS_GHC -fglasgow-exts -XTemplateHaskell #- }
```

in the documentation-part (description) of the .cabal-file I'll get the error message

```
haddock: parsing haddock prologue failed
```

when running

```
$ cabal haddock
```

but if I get rid of the `{` and `}` everything works fine. Is there some way to escape `{}` so they can be used in the description?

Comment: Looks like you can't actually have {} in the fields.  I read the parser and there doesn't seem to be any prevision for escaping the {}s which denote a non-indentation-sensitive area in the Cabal file.

(BTW, isn't "OPTIONS_GHC" deprecated?  Probably better to say `{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}`.)

I looked for examples of people trying to do this on Hackage, and all I found was (presumably) your attempt.  Maybe move the cut-n-paste code into a different file... or make a non-backward-compatible change to the parser :(

Comment: Oh yeah, and I use `test-framework-th` and I figured out what pragmas I needed without that detail in the description.  So maybe the docs are unnecessary. :)

Comment: @jrockway: Thanks. I'll just use `(...)` instead of `{...}`.

Comment: @jrockaway -- being an unanswered questions pest here -- i think you should submit your comment as an answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

Haddock has two syntaxes for code blocks -- the syntax that delimits blocks with `@` allows you to use HTML escapes, which can be used to embed characters that Cabal's parser can't deal with.

Unfortunately, it seems that Cabal strips the leading whitespace from `@`-delimited blocks, so you also have to prefix any lines with spaces with an HTML-encoded space `&#x20;`.

Here's am example:

```
description:
  My package with a code example!
  .
  @
  &#x7b;-\# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell \#-&#x7d;
  .
  main = do
  &#x20;   $templatePrint "hello!"
  &#x20;   $templatePrint "world!"
  @
```

Which renders to:

> My package with a code example!
>
> ```
> {-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
>
> main = do
>     $templatePrint "hello!"
>     $templatePrint "hello!"
> ```

Answer (score 2):

`OPTIONS_GHC` itself is not deprecated (you'd utilize this to enable particular build options, for example), but using it to turn on/off language features is not considered good practice . Use `{-# LANGUAGE ... #-}` pragmas instead.

e.g. `{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, ForeignFunctionInterface, RankNTypes #-}`

Also, it's considered bad form to utilize the all-encompassing `-fglasgow-exts`. Better to just include the extensions you need, and that way it's clearer which are required for anyone new to your code.

Comment: This is good advice, but it doesn't even attempt to answer the question.